# Show part of next and prev slides in owl Carousel 1.3.3

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, owl-carousel

I'm  currently using owlcarousel 1.3.3, and I would like on mobile device to show current slide and a part of next slide.

So i tried something with the options :

```
recoStrip: {
            // Number of items
            ...
            itemsMobile : [600, 1.3], // 1.3 items between 600 and 0
            ...
},
```

It works well, it display 1.3 items on sreen. The problem is, when I slide until the last slide,  I feel like it doesn't catch the end of the slider very well... I've no bounce effect and I can slide further than last slide...

Here is a demo :
http://jsfiddle.net/sgLqhnsd/

If any one has a tweak for that on this version of owl carousel !! Many Many thanks.

X.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

infinity scroll/circle/loop will not work in 1.3 version, you can try with latest version of Owl Carousel
http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/demos/autowidth.html

Answer (score 3):

I have changed the line 356 in the owl.carusel.js

from

```
base.maximumItem = base.itemsAmount - base.options.items;
```

to

```
base.maximumItem = Math.ceil(base.itemsAmount - base.options.items);
```

and it works fine for me